# CLlocation Getting best results Iphone

Tags: iphone, mapkit, cllocation

I'm trying to make a query based on the user location. The thing is that I can only query upon the first location result, with the lat/lon result as the query parameter. How do I make sure I get the best result of a user location and then execute the sqlite query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When the user hits the submit button, query for the location then, and add the data to the request before firing it off. You could try and predict the users location in a few seconds, but that's not really accurate.

Comment: Hi Jer, is there a way I can make sure there is no location update needed any more cause there is no better accuracy posible? 
Something like:
    if (kCLLocationAccuracyBest) { //do something }

Thanks!